# Css Class will fixed for all div without calling on each div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using simple scroll of HTML page.I am using couple of main div, inside my first div I have three other div use to call class which have images on them.
How do I make those class fixed for all other div.Say when my div 2 move up on  scrolling of page the class d c and e will stay on page scroll.
Can any one suggest me how to that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>My page</title>
    <title>jQuery Parallax Plugin Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sd.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($("#first").offset().top + $("#first").height() < $(document).scrollTop()) {
                var obj = $('#first').children('div');
                if (obj.hasClass("d")) {
                    obj.removeClass();
                }
                obj = obj.children('div');
                if (obj.hasClass("c")) {
                    obj.removeClass();
                }
                obj = obj.children('div');
                if (obj.hasClass("e")) {
                    obj.removeClass();
                }
            } else {
                var obj = $('#first').children('div');
                if (obj.hasClass("d") == false) {
                    obj.addClass("d");
                }
                obj = obj.children('div');
                if (obj.hasClass("c") == false) {
                    obj.addClass("c");
                }
                obj = obj.children('div');
                if (obj.hasClass("e") == false) {
                    obj.addClass("e");
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="first">
        <div class="d">
            <div class="c">
                <div class="e"></div>
                This is my first div to display image.
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="second">
        want to class="d" after coming in page view want to class="c" after coming in page view want to class="e" after coming in page view This is my second div to display image.
    </div>
    <div id="third">
        this is my third div
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
#first, #second {
    width: 100%;
}
#first {
    background: url('images/rc1.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    color: white;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 160px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    perspective: 1px;
}
#second {
    background: url('images/ra1.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    color: white;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 160px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    perspective: 1px;
}
#third {
    background: url('images/rc11.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    color: white;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 160px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    perspective: 1px;
}
.d {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: =218px;
    height: 73px;
    left: auto;
    top: 10%;
    background: url('images/Logo.png') top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 50px;
}
.c {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: =774px;
    height: 209px;
    left: auto;
    top: 120%;
    /*width:=137px;
   height:88px;*/
    background: url('images/big_text.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 339px;
}
.e {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: =127px;
    height: 37px;
    left: auto;
    top: 180%;
    background: url('images/scroll_text.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 680px;
}
```

Comment: Why jQuery is included twice?

Comment: In CSS, using `=` instead  of `-`. Ex. `width: =774px;`

Comment: I will remove one jquery but can u give me a hint how to resolve my current problem.A simple hint will work for me I am thinking on including .removeClass() or .hide() of jquery but don't know how to call them.Do I make separate function to call them on single window scroll bit confused